# Is it possible to pre-generate a dashboard in splunk

Tags: dashboard, splunk, spl, splunk-dashboard

Is it possible to share a pre generated dashboard?

Some search on my dashboard take up to 5 minutes to complete so i was wondering if their was a way to save the result of my dashboard so people i share my dashboard with dont have to wait another 5min in order to see the results.

Comment: You may want to consider creating a [`summary index`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/8.2.2203/Knowledge/Usesummaryindexing).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a scheduled search.  Take the search out of the dashboard and have it run at some appropriate interval.  In the dashboard, use the `loadjob` command to invoke the most recent results of the scheduled search.

This assumes, of course, that you've made all efforts to improve the search speed.